# maven testng.xml test build succesfully but it doesn't run using cmd or jenkins

Tags: xml, maven, jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I run my `testng` suite using following command. But it doesn't open any web browser. It simply gave this "Build success" message. So I want to know how to run the test suite properly.

Command:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=mytestng.xml
```

Screenshot:

[image]

TestNg.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Test121 v1.1">

    <test name="Purchase Order Form">

        <parameter name="venRefNo" value="VnRef0001"/>
        <parameter name="venBillingAddress" value="No420.Vendor Road, Vendor City"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="Procurement._01_PurchaseOrder.TestCases.TestCase_13_Procurement_PurchaseOrder" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Inbound Shipment Form">
        <classes>
            <class name="Procurement._01_PurchaseOrder.TestCases.TestCase_13_Procurement_InboundShipment" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Purchase Invoice">
        <classes>
            <class name="Procurement._01_PurchaseOrder.TestCases.TestCase_13_Procurement_PurchaseInvoice" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

POM.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test11</groupId>
    <artifactId>test11</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>test11</artifactId>
            <groupId>test11</groupId>
            <version>2.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNgSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/jenkins-core -->

</project>
```

Comment: Can you paste your testng.xml ?

Comment: sure, ill upload. same thing happen when run the project from jenkins using pom.Xml file. ill upload both.

Answer (score 0):

In command line only clean process got successful. Do you noticed any files generated in the target folders???

Comment: yes, some files has been generated with .class extension. but i lost sure-fire files and folders in the target folder.

Comment: There may be problem with the pom.xml, code in your pom is not executed fully. so target folders were cleared during clean, but not created after the it.